# Code to play Youtube video in Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

How do we play videos from YouTube as a response to google assistant app?

As of now, if I say suppose Talk to Gurudev on google assistant app, it shows some videos, when I click them, they open as pop up on google assistant.

How do we achieve this feature in our app using dialogflow and fulfillments?

Answer (score 3):

You can currently play audio files only in Actions on Google (see [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses)). However, you can add a link to a YouTube video and clicking it will open YouTube and play the video. You can use a [BasicCard](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) or [Carousel](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#carousel) for that.

Not all features of the Google Assistant are available to developers.